# Using map() function of javascript inside the find() method of mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

Earlier I was using this piece of code for db call fetch data.

```
const projectOffering = await ProjectOfferingsBudgets.find({ objectiveId: tracker.objectives.map((id)=>id)  }).lean().exec();
```

The "objectiveId" is a ObjectId type and my tracker. objectives contain an array of id(ObjectId), so I want to retrieve data from the database where this array of id matches to objectiveId in "ProjectOfferingsBudgets" collection.

But one of my colleagues told me this won't work instead try this code.

```
const projectOffering = await ProjectOfferingsBudgets.find({ objectiveId: { $in: tracker.objectives }  }).lean().exec();
```

I have tried to console the result of the 2 different codes but I am receiving the same results.
In the database, it matches 2 documents and I am getting those 2 documents in return for my code as well as my colleague's code.
So what I am asking is can we use map() inside find() method if not then why I am getting the accepted result?

Comment: ur map is redundant anyway. u are returning the same thing without any transformations. u end up with the same array. idk ur first code will work only if there exists a field with value exact array as tracker.objectives  https://mongoplayground.net/p/WFS8jlRY0cA

Comment: in short if u want to match exact array use it (same order as well) https://mongoplayground.net/p/gCMIy7sWBdI  or if  u want to query if it exists in a set of values use $in

Comment: But the find() executes at one or it will wait map function to return an array.
If so then it should throw an error because for an array there should be "$in" property to execute. @cmgchess

Comment: can you add how your mongo collection data looks like. need to know the exact structure. is your objectiveId field a string id or an array of string ids

Comment: objectiveId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
        },
above is a type of my objectId. @cmgchess
Sorry actually both of them are objectId not string. but still, why is this behavior that I am getting the result same for both code?

Comment: idk how ur first code worked then. your colleagues are correct regarding the $in. can you try to recreate a basic example on mongoplayground

Comment: here is a starter https://mongoplayground.net/p/ji2K5pWU9A6, can u try to reproduce and share

Comment: objective=[
      ObjectId("5fd4bfb796b24f5e02fd82f9"),
      ObjectId("5fd4bfb796b24f5e02fd82fa"),
      ObjectId("5fd4bfb796b24f5e02fd82fb")];
db.collection.find({
  objectiveId: objective.map((id)=>id)
})
I think i cant use javascript in it.
becouse this is giving error.

Comment: objective.map((id)=>id) what you are doing will not change anything here since u are returning the samething in the callback function.  for example if your array is [1,2,3] then [1,2,3].map(id => id) will give back the same array [1,2,3]. if u do something like [1,2,3].map(id => id*2) it will give [2,4,6]

Comment: I know, what I am asking is the array to be used inside the find() don't we need to use "$in" operator? , but without "$in" it is working and not giving errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoose `find()` is very forgiving. While it seems counter-intuitive the `find()` method will work perfectly fine being passed an array in this case as you have found out. It is more semantic using the `$in` operator but these examples below return identical results. Given an array of ObjectIds:

```js
const arr = [
   new ObjectId("650ecb0f507561a33ce927aa"), 
   new ObjectId("65128fb671522f4d58dabd55")
];
```

Both these queries return the same results:

```js
const users1 = await Model.find({_id: arr}); //< Pass just the array

const users2 = await Model.find({_id: {$in: arr}}); //< Pass array using $in
```

To answer your last question "*So what I am asking is can we use map() inside find() method*". Then yes, you can run a function as long as it's return value is something the enclosing function expects as a parameter then you can of course call it.

Comment: well, I guess I will consider this as unusual behavior of find() but I don't find this in any official doc. that it can also work this way.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes you have to be careful because this will not work in the mongosh shell, only using mongoose. It will also work with strings etc, not just an array of ObjectIds. Remember though, mongoose is an object modelling package that has additional features to the shell and native mongodb driver. I would agree that it is unanticipated behaviour.

Comment: yes Got it, when I tried to use this on MongoDB Compass it didn't work, it only works for Mongoose.